# When I put @Autowire annotaion for JAX WS class it gives null pointer exception error in spring boot

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-boot, jax-ws, autowired

I write a JAX-WS service for my web application and when I call to the web service it gives the null pointer exception(Autowire not working)... I us tomcat 8.5.11 as a server...

When **I remove the @WebService annotaion the autowire works fine.... But when i add it it doesn't work**... What is the error... Is it error becomes with my dependencies...

This is my Dependencies.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!--handle servlet-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!--<Email Dependency>-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<!--Add mysql dependency-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
<!--jasper-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.6</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.10</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-rt -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.8</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jvnet.staxex/stax-ex -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.staxex</groupId>
    <artifactId>stax-ex</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.8</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.stream.buffer/streambuffer -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.stream.buffer</groupId>
    <artifactId>streambuffer</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-libs -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-libs</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

My Model is annotated with @Entity annotation..I'm not put it here...

My repository is

```java
package lk.slsi.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import java.util.List;
import lk.slsi.domain.CustomsPermit;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
@Qualifier("PermitRepository")
public interface PermitRepository extends CrudRepository < CustomsPermit, Long > {
    @Query("select a from CustomsPermit a where a.dtIssue = :dtIssue")
    List < CustomsPermit > getPermitByDate(@Param("dtIssue") String dtIssue);
}
```

My WS class is

```java
package lk.slsi.repository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import lk.slsi.domain.CustomsPermit;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport;

/**
 *
 * @author lankadeva.ghg
 */
@WebService
@Component
public class permitRepoImpl extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("PermitRepository")
    private PermitRepository permitRepository;

    public static void marshaling() throws JAXBException {
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(CustomsPermit.class);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        } catch (JAXBException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(permitRepoImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public List < CustomsPermit > getPermitByDate(String dtIssue) {
        try {
            System.out.println("autowire is " + permitRepository);
            marshaling();
        } catch (JAXBException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(permitRepoImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.out.println("exception : autowire is " + permitRepository);
            return (List < CustomsPermit > ) ex;
        }
        return permitRepository.getPermitByDate(dtIssue);
    }
}
```

The Autowire doesn't works in here...**When I go on debug mode it gives null as a value**

This is my web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>SLSIonNationalSingleWindow</display-name>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>permitRepoImplService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/permitRepoImplService</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/view/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:slsi-servlet-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>permitRepoImplService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This is my applicationconfig.xml

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!-- Scan Config -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="lk.slsi" />
    <!--<mvc:annotation-driven/>-->
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
                  value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!--<bean id = "permitRepository" class="lk.slsi.repository.PermitRepository"
          autowire="byName" autowire-candidate="true">
    </bean>-->
</beans>
```

**What is the error in my dependency injection....**

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding this dependency : jaxws-spring library that integrates the two frameworks:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring</groupId>
 <artifactId>jaxws-spring</artifactId>
 <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Refer this link for more :
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jws/jax-ws-spring-integration-example/

Comment: Yeah i add this earlier..But it doesn't do anything...I s this dependency need special configuration

Comment: can we use autowire without Autowired annotation.. I means by implementiong class... But I dont hace a idea how can i return repository by implement class...

Comment: You can use Autowired  annotation, this dependency probably tells spring to autowire components in web service controller

Comment: I add this plugging..But error is the same...Is this pluging need to tell End point interface with parenthesis @WebService annotation